# POST request fails with no error message (Parse.com / ExpressJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I'm experiencing an issue where a POST request I make fails with error code 500 and nothing is printed in my server side error log. It's almost as if the cloud method doesn't exist for it.

What is strange though, is that the same POST request performs fine with smaller files. It starts to fail when the file gets to around 1.4 MB. I've tried changing the limit parameter of express.bodyParser like so "app.use(express.bodyParser( { limit: 10000000 } ));", however this makes no difference.

Here's some code:

```
function uploadFile(pageState)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function()
    {
        var data = reader.result;

        var byteArrayObj = new Uint8Array(data);
        var byteArray = new Array(byteArrayObj.length);
        for(i=0; i<byteArray.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i] = byteArrayObj[i];
        }

        var json = { data: byteArray };
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "/assetUploader/"+pageState.assetIdentifier+"/"+pageState.fileName+"/"+pageState.isAssetBundle+"/"+pageState.uploadToProduction, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        xmlhttp.onload = function(evt) {
            ...
        };

        xmlhttp.send(jsonString);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer( pageState.fileRef );
}
```

On the cloud side:

```
app.post('/assetUploader/:fileIdentifier/:fileName/:isAssetBundle/:useProd', function(req, res)
{
    console.log("assetUpload Post");
    var fileId = req.params.fileIdentifier;
    var fileName = req.params.fileName;
    var assetBundle = req.params.isAssetBundle  == "true";
    var bytes = req.body.data;
    var useProd = req.params.useProd == "true";

    createParseFile(fileName, bytes, useProd).then( function(response) {
        return currentVersionForAsset(fileId, useProd).then(function(versionNumber) {
            return {
                "fileIdentifier": fileId,
                "file": {
                        "name": response.data.name,
                    "__type": "File"
                    },
                "isAssetBundle": assetBundle,
                "fileVersion": versionNumber+1
            };
        });
    }).then(function(json) {
        return createParseObject("DownloadableAsset", json, useProd);
    }).then( function() {
            res.send(200);
        }, function(error) {
        res.send(400, error.message);
    });
});
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: you get any error in console

Comment: would it be viable for you to create a cloud code function that uses Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest? https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking-post

Comment: As stated, no errors in either the browsers console or parse's log. Unfortunately I need to make the request from the browser and Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest is a server-side method. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

i suggest using res.setTimeout with a very large number of milisecs. perhaps your response simply times out, and from my experience node doesn't throw an error when it happens.

Comment: I was hoping this was it, but alas- the onload callback is being called, not the ontimeout (for the clientside XmlHttpRequest). Even if I put in a huge number as suggested.

Comment: If you meant calling this in the cloud function, I can't seem to find a setTimeout method on either the "req" or "res" parameters. Thank you for the suggestion though!